# Which eclipse with java and selenium is suitable for windows 10?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, windows-10

I am getting problem of jar files every time, as I had downloaded correct jar files, eclipse and java.

I was expecting to work with eclipse but every time java.lang.module.FindException error appears. After inserting jar files in the path then also the eclipse is not able to read the jar files and I get chrome-driver error and the setup issue creates. Therefore, I want complete proper setup details of eclipse java. I tried from you tube but it won't worked at all.

Comment: The latest Eclipse with the included Java 17 and a Maven project that specifies the needed dependencies (needed JARs) in the `pom.xml` file should work out of the box. Otherwise, please tell exactly which software you have and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently, your question only says it is not working which is not enough to tell what is going wrong in your specific case.

Comment: Eclipse version is 2021-12-R win32-x86 64 and Selenium java version is 4.11.0 I am using.

Comment: Apart from the fact that your Eclipse is several release behind (which you should fix first), what is your question? Please edit your question, and show your code. If you follow a tutorial, make sure it is up to date.

Comment: if you're not using maven, be aware that the selenium zip file will have a folder inside called "lib".  Those jars will also need to be added as dependencies... and don't add any jars that say "-sources" or you'll end up with all kinds of conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

***Eclipse IDE 2023‑06*** is the latest [eclipse release](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) which comes with [java-17](/questions/tagged/java-17) bundle works seamless on my [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) box along with the latest [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) version ***v4.10***